# SwiftUI View Modifier .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard) not working as expected

Tags: swift, swiftui

My SwiftUI View is pushed up by the keyboard despite using the `.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)` modifier:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct PushUpView: View {
    @State var random = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            Color.clear
            VStack {
                ForEach(0..<25) { id in
                    Text("Text: \(id)")
                }
                TextField("Hello, World!", text: $random)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
    }
}
```

Pursuant to the following threads:

- [swiftui-in-ios14-keyboard-avoidance-issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63968241/swiftui-in-ios14-keyboard-avoidance-issues-and-ignoressafearea-modifier-issues)
- [how-to-prevent-keyboard-from-pushing-up-the-view-in-swiftui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67105632/how-to-prevent-keyboard-from-pushing-up-the-view-in-swiftui)
- [swiftui-ios14-disable-keyboard-avoidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65701064/swiftui-ios14-disable-keyboard-avoidance)

I thought that by using `Spacer()`, and by putting the keyboard avoid-er on a `ZStack` that has a `Color.clear` background that takes up all available space I'd be safe.

Alas, the problem persists. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried using GeometryReader? the view won't move up if you use it.